# lodash groupby key if exist in collection

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have below an array

```
{
  "sec": "11",
  "details": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "user": "Me1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "uesr": "Me2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user": "Me3"
    }
    {
      "id": "4",
      "user": "Me4",
      parentID:"2"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "uesr": "Me5"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "user": "Me6",
      parentID:"2"
    }
    {
      "id": "7",
      "user": "Me7"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "uesr": "Me8",
      parentID:"7"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "user": "Me9",
      parentID:"7"
    }
  ],
  "isDisplay": "true"
}
```

and output should be like below

```
{
"sec":"11",
"details":[
{
"id":"1",
"user":"Me1"
},
{
"id":"2",
"uesr":"Me2",
"childs":[
{
"id":"4",
"user":"Me4",
"parentID":"2"
},
{
"id":"6",
"user":"Me6",
"parentID":"2"
}
]
},
{
"id":"3",
"user":"Me3"
},
{
"id":"5",
"uesr":"Me5"
},
{
"id":"7",
"user":"Me7",
"childs":[
{
"id":"8",
"uesr":"Me8",
"parentID":"7"
},
{
"id":"9",
"user":"Me9",
"parentID":"7"
}
]
}
],
"isDisplay":"true"
}
```

I can do this by simple looping,

In lodash or anything angular does this functionality.

I am clueless to start,
I just give below code

```
this.list = _.groupBy(this.list,"parentID");
```

But the output not as expected.

Please help or guide

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic: you may want to sanitize your array; I see sometimes `user`, sometimes `uesr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different approach, not grouping, but creating a tree out of the related data.

This solution uses an array with `id` as key and with `parentID` as well. The code works with a single loop, because of storing of the relation of children and parent and parent to their children.

> How it works:
>
> Basically for every object in the array it takes as well the `id` for building a new object as the `parentID` for a new object.
>
> So for example this object
>
> ```
> { id: "6", parentID: "2", user: "Me6" }
> ```
>
> it generates in `o` first with `id` this property
>
> ```
> 6: {
>     id: "6",
>     parentID: "2",
>     user: "Me6"
> }
> ```
>
> and then this property with `parentID`
>
> ```
> 2: {
>     children: [
>         {
>             id: "6",
>             parentID: "2",
>             user: "Me6"
>         }
>     ]
> },
> ```
>
> and while all object treated like this, we finally get a tree.
>
> At the end, the children array of the root property is returned.

```js
function getTree(data, root) {
    var o = {};
    data.forEach(function (a) {
        if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
            a.children = o[a.id].children;
        }
        o[a.id] = a;
        o[a.parentID] = o[a.parentID] || {};
        o[a.parentID].children = o[a.parentID].children || [];
        o[a.parentID].children.push(a);
    });
    return o[root].children;
}

var data = { sec: "11", details: [{ id: "1", user: "Me1" }, { id: "2", uesr: "Me2" }, { id: "3", user: "Me3" }, { id: "4", user: "Me4", parentID: "2" }, { id: "5", uesr: "Me5" }, { id: "6", user: "Me6", parentID: "2" }, { id: "7", user: "Me7" }, { id: "8", user: "Me8", parentID: "7" }, { id: "9", user: "Me9", parentID: "7" }], isDisplay: "true" },
    result = { sec: "11", details: getTree(data.details, undefined), isDisplay: "true" };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it is again loop coding, i was wondering if there any inbuilt in lodash

Comment: I am finding it very difficult to understand it... could you please give some guidance how this is working

Comment: Thanks amazing gesture of helping, I am facing issue with getting total items count in a root..

Comment: you could ask another question and present the problem with the code, you tried. in comments, it is not the right place to answer additional tasks.

Comment: Ok. sure let me ask another question