# Getting all count of nested items

Tags: javascript, angular

I have below a post referencing [lodash groupby key if exist in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374145/lodash-groupby-key-if-exist-in-collection) and returns the below structure.

```
{
  "sec": "11",
  "details": [{
      "id": "1",
      "user": "Me1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "uesr": "Me2",
      "childs": [{
          "id": "4",
          "user": "Me4",
          "parentID": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "user": "Me6",
          "parentID": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user": "Me3"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "uesr": "Me5"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "user": "Me7",
      "childs": [{
          "id": "8",
          "uesr": "Me8",
          "parentID": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "user": "Me9",
          "parentID": "7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "isDisplay": "true"
}
```

I need to get total count of all nested items, like in sec 11, there is 9 items.

Comment: Can you explain what you need ?

Comment: I have given at end

Comment: You have written, in sec 11 there are 9 items.. but what Items you want to count?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the count of the inner arrays and count this values to the actual level.

```js
const
    getCount = (s, { childs }) => (childs || []).reduce(getCount, s + 1),
    data = { sec: "11", details: [{ id: "1", user: "Me1" }, { id: "2", uesr: "Me2", childs: [{ id: "4", user: "Me4", parentID: "2" }, { id: "6", user: "Me6", parentID: "2" }] }, { id: "3", user: "Me3" }, { id: "5", uesr: "Me5" }, { id: "7", user: "Me7", childs: [{ id: "8", uesr: "Me8", parentID: "7" }, { id: "9", user: "Me9", parentID: "7" }] }], isDisplay: "true" },
    count = data.details.reduce(getCount, 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count all the items with a recursive `function`, that uses a simple `.forEach()` call over the given `array`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var items = 0;
function countItems(arr) {
  arr.forEach(a => {
    items += 1;
    if (a.childs)
      countItems(a.childs);
  });
}
countItems(data.details);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  "sec": "11",
  "details": [{
      "id": "1",
      "user": "Me1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "uesr": "Me2",
      "childs": [{
          "id": "4",
          "user": "Me4",
          "parentID": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "user": "Me6",
          "parentID": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user": "Me3"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "uesr": "Me5"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "user": "Me7",
      "childs": [{
          "id": "8",
          "uesr": "Me8",
          "parentID": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "user": "Me9",
          "parentID": "7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "isDisplay": "true"
};

var items = 0;
function countItems(arr) {
  arr.forEach(a => {
    items += 1;
    if (a.childs)
      countItems(a.childs);
  });
}
countItems(data.details);

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will be extracting `sec-11` object. You can use Array.reduce and recursive function to get the results.

```js
let obj = {"sec":"11","details":[{"id":"1","user":"Me1"},{"id":"2","uesr":"Me2","childs":[{"id":"4","user":"Me4","parentID":"2"},{"id":"6","user":"Me6","parentID":"2"}]},{"id":"3","user":"Me3"},{"id":"5","uesr":"Me5"},{"id":"7","user":"Me7","childs":[{"id":"8","uesr":"Me8","parentID":"7"},{"id":"9","user":"Me9","parentID":"7"}]}],"isDisplay":"true"};

function getCount(obj) {
  if(obj.childs) return obj.childs.reduce((a,c) => a + getCount(c) + 1, 0)
  return 0;
}

let sum = obj.details.reduce((a,c) => a + getCount(c) + 1, 0);
console.log(sum);
```